# Run java program in environment without file system?

Tags: java, jvm

I was wondering is it possible to have such run environment for jvm that it will run without file system?
I am trying to isolate all places in my program that there will be no calls to `FileSystems.getDefault()` and they will be replaced with my own file system (in-memory jimfs for example)

**UPD**

In comments people saying that it's possible. Are there any flags in JVM that I could provide to disable mapping to my laptop's HDD? How do I do this?

Comment: Yes it is.  You only need a file system to use files.

Comment: Something about this seems almost "cart-before-horse".  If you're going to be writing files out, why aren't you able to specify specifically where they live - be that in memory or otherwise?

Comment: Web apps don't usually deal with the file system.  I don't see why it can't be done.

Comment: @james large That's true, but it doesn't have to, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_Java

Comment: @Makoto, it's not simple as you think. There are lot's of 3rd party libraries which are not using java.nio, and using for example `File.createTempFile`